# Lex what does this regular expression

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

I'm learning `lex` and I have some doubt's.

I have some regular expressions in one file and them i have this three (this is for matching Java comments):

```
"//".*"\n" {LINE+=1; COLUMN=1;}
\/\/.*     {LINE+=1; COLUMN=1;}
\n         {LINE+=1; COLUMN=1;}
```

I believe that the second regular expression is the same as `"//".*`.

I understand that the first matches comments started with `//` followed by zero or more characters and then a new line. The second does the same thing but without the new line.

My doubt is this. Doesn't the combination of the second with the third regular expression do exactly the same thing as the first one?

I'm submitting this to a test platform and without the first expression it says that I have an error and with the first expression I says that is correct but I can't seem to find a example that without the first regular expression a comment is not matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of the second and third regular expression certainly match the same strings as does the first regular expression, but they don't act on those strings the same way. If you leave out the first rule and action, then lexing the input

```
// Some comment
```

will result in `{LINE+=1; COLUMN=1;}` being executed twice, so that `LINE` will be incremented by 2. If your test harness cares about the correctness of `LINE` and `COLUMN`, then that won't be regarded as correct.

It is certainly the case that the first pattern is unnecessary. You could instead use:

```
"//".*     { COLUMN += yyleng;      }
\n         { LINE += 1; COLUMN = 1; }
```

There is one case in which `"//".*\n` won't match a comment: if the comment is the last line of the input and the input is not terminated with a newline character. Technically, a valid text (source) file must be terminated by a newline character, since the newline is actually a line terminator and not a line separator or line starter, as its common name might imply. However, most compilers will allow unterminated input lines.

Anyway, the input might have blank and uncommented lines, so you'll need to recognize `\n` whether or not it is part of a comment, as long as you are tracking line numbers and column positions yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation...You were right on. Made your change suggestion and it passes all my tests